# Edit data in a particular Table cell in MS-Word using C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I am trying to develop a program to find and edit the contents of a particular cell in MS-word using C#. Is there some method such as setting variable name or a namespace for a particular cell in word so as to change its contents using C#?

Tried using OpenXML, Interop, DocX but due to multiple occurrences of same data and complex tables, didn't work out as the tables are nested.

Comment: What is the path to the table cell you're trying to edit? You said you've tried using Interop, and that should be all you need to edit the table cell. What is the exact problem that you're having?

Comment: @Meloviz There are multiple tables inside each table, also I need to get and set data from lot of cells, hence using the interop method becomes too complicated. Is there some way such as assigning a variable name to a particular table cell and accessing it directly?

Comment: Inside the document before you need to edit it in your program, I don't know. But if you can access it through interop, you should be able to assign a name to it. I know it's more complex, but that's just how the interop models are unfortunately. I've always use interop, and sometimes I have quite a few levels down before I finally get what I want. I've yet to find a better way.

Comment: Select the cell and insert a BOOKMARK. The bookmark can then be addressed through the interop, directly, irregardless whether in a table, in a nested table, header, footer...